# Can and should moderators delete comments with out moving them and notifying users?

Tags: discussion, moderation

A user very active on this site in the comments of this answer (https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82516/28966) was, in my opinion, using and justifying ethnic cleansing euphemisms, and I called it out. The discussion got a bit out of hand, and I anticipated it being moved to the chat, which I was absolutely fine with.

However, it seems a moderator simply...deleted the entire conversation, without any notification in my inbox of it being moved, or a moderator comment explaining that it had been moved. This seems quite strange to me. The discussion was very much on topic and related to both the question and the answer. However, as it was getting extended, by all means it should have been moved to the chat.

What is the justification for wiping comments like this? Is this normal in this community?

If it is necessary, I can describe the conversation, but I doubt that is necessary and I'd rather avoid it as it was very distasteful in my view.

Comment: I'm not privy to what was said in those deleted comments, but personally I'm having trouble reconciling "The discussion got a bit out of hand" and "The discussion was very much on topic".

Comment: "A bit out of hand" meaning it was going on too long (extended discussion in the comments). I even elaborated this in my question: "However, as it was getting extended". The entire discussion was on topic

Comment: Unless the euphemisms are in the *answer* that they were under the discussion didn't belong. I didn't see the comments, so dunno what was said. As for the rest of the Q, the answer is yes, comments get deleted w/o warning. See e.g. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/does-politics-se-have-a-problem-with-too-many-comments

Comment: @Fizz the euphemism was not in the answer; the original commenter was insisting that the euphemism be used instead of the actual term, to which I objected. Thanks for the clarity, will just answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering via info from @Fizz: comments can and do get deleted without warning, see [Does Politics.SE have a problem with too many comments?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/does-politics-se-have-a-problem-with-too-many-comments)